# Print with color - is it possible?

Tags: front-end, output-formatting

I want to color parts of what `Print` prints.
Is there anything to switch the color for all subsequent print items?

Comment: Can you give an example of an expression you'd like to print, and the part that you'd like to appear in a different colour?

Comment: `Print[Style["Text",Red]]` prints the string `Text` in red. It is difficult to go further without a more specific question.

Comment: Try `Print[Row[{Style["T",Black],Style["e",Red],Style["xt",Black]}]]`.

Comment: Define a function: `print[x_, style_ : Black] := Print[Style[x, style]]` and use: `print[2.56, Orange]; print["Hello", Blue]`

Comment: `Print` print a `Cell` of style `"Print"`, whose style definitions you could change. However, since the style is rendered in the front end, a change to the style would change all `"Print"` cells, both previous and subsequent, in the notebook(s) to which the style definition is applied. You will probably have to do it yourself with `Style` as other show above, using a variable to keep track of the current style to be printed.

Comment: Your comments almost gave me what I am after: Her an example following your suggestions: `Print["This is normal text. "
 , Style["Watch out: ", RGBColor["#A00000"], Bold, Underlined]
 , "Don't overlook this!"
 , Style["The square root of 2 is " <> ToString[N[Sqrt[2]]], Blue]
 , " Now back to black."
 , Style[" Green is also possible.", RGBColor["#008000"], Bold]
 ]`. But isn't there something which lets me stay closer to the syntax of print rather than convertoing everything to string by hand?

Comment: There is a menucommand for adding `StyleBox` conveniently in the menu `Format`.

Comment: Which one do you mean: I can chooses between Style (►=with submenus) / Clear / Clear Formatting / Stylesheet► / ScreenEnvironment► / Edit Stylesheet / OptionInspector/ Font / Face► / Size► / TextColor► / Background Color► / Cell Dingbat►/ Text Algnment► / Text Justification► / WordWrapping►   in Mma 12.3.